# Is stepping back to begin shemonah esrei in front of one who had started a moment early also a problem?

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei

You're not supposed to walk within 4 cubits of someone praying the amidah because the shechinah is in that radius ([source](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shemoneh_Esrei#Walking_in_front_of_someone_Davening)).

Is stepping back to begin shemonah esrei in front of one who had started a moment earlier also a problem or is the application only applicable at the end of the amidah?

Comment: I actually found myself wondering this today in a crowded shul. +1

Answer (score 2):

**or is the application only applicable at the end of the amidah?**

> Similarly, it’s forbidden to take the three steps before Shemonah Esrei in front of someone Davening [Halichot Shlomo 8:33][(Source)](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shmoneh_Esrei#Taking_Three_Steps_Back)

Interestingly, some say not to take the three steps at all if that involves going in front of someone praying:

> If taking 3 steps back involves walking into the 4 amot of someone Davening, don’t take these steps back at all and just start Shmoneh Esrei. [Halichot Shlomo 8:33, Piskei Teshuvot 95:5] ([Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Taking_Three_Steps_Back))

Comment: Honestly i don't know who wrote hilchot shlomo, but what he said here makes allot of sense.

Comment: I believe R Shlomo Zalman Auerbach wrote Halichot Shlomo. Of course he makes sense :->

Comment: Correction: The Halichot shlomo was not written by R' SZ Auerbach himself but by his Grandchildren citing his psakim and minhagim . It is accepted as one of the most authoritative sources on the halachic opinions of R' SZ Auerbach.